# Power bi paginated report hide rows

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I am currently working on a Power BI paginated report, and I need to display only the rows where the "State" column is blank. However, in the grand total section, I would like to show the total including all values, regardless of the filters applied.

For instance, let's consider the following example:

ID State Amount

1       10
2       10
3   NY  20
4   CA  30
5   TX  30
In this scenario, I would like to display only the first two rows where the "State" column is blank in my tablix.  In the sub-total, I would like to show the sum of the amounts for these blank rows (which is 20). In the grand total, I want to show the sum of amounts for all the rows (which is 80), including those with non-blank values in the "State" column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyM7O.png)

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve this requirement in my Power BI paginated report. Thank you for your assistance.